# Path independence of a conservative force

Tags: forces, classical-mechanics, work, integration, conservative-field

My book Halliday et al. gives a proof of the path independence (conservative force). It is said that the net work to move a particle from a to b and then from b to a is zero. Thus the work done from a to b equals minus the work done from b to a.
The book states that minus the work done from b to a equals the work done from a to b along the same path if the force is conservative. I tried to understand why this is true.
According to math, minus the integral from b to a of the force scalar ds equals the integral from a to b of the force scalar ds. This is why the equivalence above is true. I think it is only a matter of math, not physics.

Comment: You are correct, if you specify that it’s along the same path it’s just a property of integrals. For a conservative force it is true that $W_{AB} = -W_{BA}$ regardless of what path is taken.

Comment: Yes, the path is the same, obviously. Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/541052/

Answer (score 1):

While it is true that the properties of integrals is critical to showing that the work done by a conservative force is path independent, the nature of the potential - i.e. the physics of the system - determines that it is conservative.  The fact that a gravitational field assumes the mathematical form that is does leads to a conservative force.

Thus, so it is with a non-conservative forces as well, the classic example being friction, the nature of it (the physics) determines this property as well.  Since a friction force is dependent upon the velocity, you could actually retrace the exact same path forwards and backwards between two points, and if your velocity profile is different, do different amounts of work.

Comment: The equivalence explained above is given by a property of integrals, isn't it? It is not the result of the nature of the force, which is conservative.

Comment: Yes, but with the non-conservative friction force example, the nature of integrals hasn't changed - the nature of the force has changed.  So the physical nature of the force, which is represented by the mathematics used to describe it, plays a role here as well.

Answer (score 0):

> The book states that minus the work done from b to a equals the work
> done from a to b along the same path if the force is conservative. I
> tried to understand why this is true.

A common example will help.

You lift an object of mass $m$ at rest on the ground and bring it to rest a height $h$ above the ground. The upward force that you apply is in the same direction as the displacement of the object, so you do positive work equal to $+mgh$.

At the same time you lift the object, the force of gravity acts downward on the object, opposite the direction of the displacement of the object. So gravity does negative work equal to $-mgh$. The sum of the work that you do plus the work by gravity is zero, for a net work done on the object of zero. Since the object starts and ends at rest, there is no overall change in its kinetic energy. Per the work energy theorem, the net work done on an object equals its change in kinetic energy.

In the example of lifting the object, by doing negative work gravity takes the energy you gave the object by your positive work and stores it as gravitational potential energy of the earth-object system.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is not what I was looking for. Sorry.

Comment: OK. No problem.